# Why is sphinx automodule not showing any module members?

Tags: python, module, python-sphinx, autodoc

I started working on a python module and wanted to document the code "in place". So i set up sphinx in a subdirectory with sphinx-quickstart resulting in this directory structure (only the files i edited are shown):

- myproject/

  - __init__.py
  - main.py
- docs/ (sphinx directory)

  - build/
  - source/

    - conf.py
    - index.rst
- setup.py

My index.rst contains:

```
Welcome to My Module's documentation!
=====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. automodule:: myproject
    :members:


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

When i run

```
make html
```

i get a documentation that is missing the automodule part allthough i documented every class and every method in main.py like this:

```
class Thing:
    """This class represents Things

    :param color: how the thing should look like
    """

    def __init__(self, color):
        pass

    def color(self):
        """Tells you the color of the thing.

        :returns: Color string
        :rtype: str or unicode
        """
        pass
```

Sys.path is also setup correctly, as it throws now error when making

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
```

If it is relevant i also include the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='My Module',
      version='0.1',
      description='Internet of Things',
      url='https://example.com',
      author='Master Yoda',
      author_email='yoda@example.com',
      license='GPLv3',
      packages=['mymodule'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

What can i change to make autodoc work?

Comment: I don't understand how `.. automodule:: mymodule` can work. You don't have a module with that name. I would expect `.. automodule:: myproject.main` to work.

Comment: @mzjn you were right! I had to write "automodule:: myproject.main" to make it work. Thank you so much. Do you want to answer this question? :)

Comment: I accidentially wrote `mymodule` instead of `myproject` in my question, but this was not the reason why it did not work in the original code. However i mixed up module and package and wrote `myproject` instead of `myproject.main`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `main` module is in the `myproject` package. In order to document `main`, you need the following:

```
.. automodule:: myproject.main
   :members:
```

Answer (score 9):

If your class is imported into `__init__.py` you may also need `:imported-members:` like so:

```
.. automodule:: myproject
   :imported-members:
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```